# npm install failing missing dezalgo

Tags: cordova, npm, npm-install

npm install cordova-android@5.2.2   fails with below

```
npm ERR! path /Users/Barry/Desktop/demo/node_modules/npm/node_modules/dezalgo
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/Barry/Desktop/demo/node_modules/npm/node_modules/dezalgo' -> '/Users/Barry/Desktop/demo/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.dezalgo.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Barry/.npm/_logs/2018-01-10T23_36_50_656Z-debug.log
```

True the Directory does not exist, yet I have never installed this package and don't know what it is  (I'm assuming a dependencies for something) it is also NOT listed in my package.json

Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm got the same error trying to install axios with `npm install --save axios` on a create-react-app app.

Manually adding axios in my `package.json`

`"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.17.1",
  ...
},`

and doing:

`rm -Rf node_modules`

and then reinstalling the packages:

`npm install`

worked for me.

Something is definitly wonky in NPM for this to happen I think.

Comment: Thanks I don't have axios,  but I also tried your process and that didn't work for me.. I end up with the same error